# Firefox Add-on : How to get value of address bar?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am trying to build a firefox addon. Can anyone tell me how can I get the value of address bar ?

currently I am using the below code but I dont want to enter the url in a seperate text box . Instead I want to take value from address bar which i am going to type.

My code should do the rest.
Currently code takes the value from textbox

JavaScript Code:

```
function Doit()
{
var url = document.getElementById('txtSource').value;
url = url.replace('www.', 'myvalue.whatever.');
var dest = document.getElementById('txtDest');
dest.value = url;
window.open(url,'_newtab');
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="txtSource"/><br><br>
<input type="button" value="ACDEV" onClick="Doit();"/>
<input type="hidden" id="txtDest">
```

Output should be:
when I enter http://www.something.com addon should create http://myvalue.something.com on click of addon icon

Comment: as of now , no error. but I want to add the same functionality without using textbox, instead my code should take address bar value

Answer (score 3):

Use **`document.URL`** to get your job done.

The `document.URL` or `document.location` returns a read only string. You can't change the `document.URL`, but you can change the window location.

The **`window.location.href`** property is the same as the `document.URL`, `window.location.href` can be used for server redirect.

Answer (score 2):

Use `location.href` to retrieve the value

You also should modify your replace-pattern to avoid unexpected results on URLs like

```
http://something.www.anotherthing.com
```

or

```
http://something.com/www.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

For the addon you can use following code to get URL from the address bar

Javascript code:

```
function Doit(){
   var link = window.top.getBrowser().selectedBrowser.contentWindow.location.href;
   alert (link); 
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div onclick = "Doit()">Generate URL</div>
```

This will generate the URL presented on the present tab of the browser.